# Multi-auth not working 5.4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I have 2 users which is seller and user. Login function for both is fine but when I login to seller there is no logout button.
[image]

Route:

```
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\PsController@logout');
```

psblade:

```
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ route('ps.login') }}">Loginnn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('ps.register') }}">Registerr</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ route('/logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

Comment: Don't you have a dropdown when you click the name of the user in the right?

Comment: Nope the dropdown is not appear